# When should I use next, upcoming and coming?

Tags: adjectives

I'd like to know when should I use *"next"*, *"upcoming"* and *"coming"*?

> The Associated Press (AP) earlier on Monday reported the doses would
> be shared in ***coming*** months following their clearance by the FDA.

My doubt is, on the phrase above could I use *"next"* or *"upcoming"* too? Could explain me the grammar rule applicable to too?

Comment: You can't use _next_ on its own in this context - it would have to be _the next month_ or _the next few months_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all mean basically the same thing -- some arbitrary months in the near future:

- "in coming months"
- "in the next few months" (this *may* suggest more immediacy than other options, but not necessarily)
- "in the upcoming months" (this is awkward and uncommon)

This means next month:

- "next month"

These are not valid:

- "in next month"
- "in next months"
- "in upcoming months" (this is almost valid, but awkward)